# Echo is not showing up in api

Tags: php

I'm trying to make an api for my iOS application by sending `POST http requests` to my `api.php`. I'm testing it right now, but my echo is not showing up? The only moment my echo works is when I delete everything and just write `echo 'Test';`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $user = '';
    $pass = '';

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=iOS', $user, $pass); 


    if(isset($_POST['status']) && $_POST['status'] == "login")){
        // Login stuff
    }else if(isset($_POST['status']) && $_POST['status'] == "registreren")){
        //Register stuff
        if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['email']))){

            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `user` (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";

            if($dbh->execute($sql)){
                echo 'Did it';
            }else{
                echo 'Nop';
            }
        }

    }else{
        echo 'Something is wrong';
    }

    $dbh = null; // PDO sluiten
?>
```

I'm not so good at php, but in my case there should always return `'Something is wrong'` when accessing the `api.php` by URL because I don't send any `POST requests` with it.

Comment: Syntax error: `if(isset($_POST['status']) && $_POST['status'] == "registreren"))` should be `if(isset($_POST['status']) && $_POST['status'] == "registreren")`. Also check the other if-statements for additional brackets.

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: it may be because $_POST['status'] neither equals login nor registreren

Comment: @Vivek He said he's not sending any POST parameters, so it shouldn't be set at all. That's why it should fall through to the last `else`.

Comment: @RST else if == elseif in that case anyway

Comment: @Birk Is correct, unless you added the extra parenthesis when copying here. Check your PHP error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several syntax errors which might prevent your code from executing correctly. In every if-statement, there is an additional bracket.

Eg: `if(isset($_POST['status']) && $_POST['status'] == "registreren"))` should be replaced by `if(isset($_POST['status']) && $_POST['status'] == "registreren")` (note that the last bracket is missing).

Remove the additional brackets at the end of **every** if-statement in your code and it might be fine.

Comment: Thanks! The error reporting from my PHP was not on. So i've enabled it!